# Mapping over an array of objects to generate React components based on the key value pairs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

EDIT: None of the solutions below worked for me as they were so after fiddling with ido ben ami's one I got this to work:

```
{
    array.map(project =>
        <Box>
            <Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{fontWeight: 'bold', ml: 2}}
                        value={Object.keys(project)[0]}>{Object.keys(project)[0]}</Typography>
            {
                Object.entries(project)[0][1].map(ticket =>
                    <MenuItem sx={{ml: 3}} value={ticket}>{ticket}</MenuItem>)
            }
        </Box>
    )
}
```

I had originally used fragments instead of Box but Material UI doesn't like that for Select. If I left out one of these two it didn't work because the 2 components being generated are not the same.

The data from my backend is as such (number of projects/tickets varies obviously):

```
[
    {
        "Project 1": [
            "Ticket 1",
            "Ticket 2",
            "Ticket 3",
        ]
    },
    {
        "Project 2": [
            "Ticket 4"
            "Ticket 5"
            "Ticket 6"
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to map over it to generate items for my Select component. This is the outcome I'm after but I can't figure out how to do it with Object.entries or Object.keys/Object.values:

```
<Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{fontWeight: 'bold', ml: 2}} value="Project 1">Project 1</Typography>
<MenuItem sx={{ml: 3}} value="Ticket 1">Ticket 1</MenuItem>
<MenuItem sx={{ml: 3}} value="Ticket 2">Ticket 2</MenuItem>
<MenuItem sx={{ml: 3}} value="Ticket 3">Ticket 3</MenuItem>

<Typography variant="subtitle1" sx={{fontWeight: 'bold', ml: 2}} value="Project 2">Project 2</Typography>
<MenuItem sx={{ml: 3}} value="Ticket 4">Ticket 4</MenuItem>
<MenuItem sx={{ml: 3}} value="Ticket 5">Ticket 5</MenuItem>
<MenuItem sx={{ml: 3}} value="Ticket 6">Ticket 6</MenuItem>
```

Comment: `array.map(typo => Object.keys(typo).map(key => ( <Typography ... value={{ key }}>{{ key }}</Typography>{typo[key].map(ticket => ( <MenuItem ... value={{ ticket }}>{{ ticket }}</MenuItem> ))})))`? Just off the cuff...

Comment: My linter is telling me that theres something wrong with the syntax. Ive been toying with it but I can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<Box>
        {array.map((project, projectIndex) => (
            <Box key={projectIndex}>
                {console.log(Object.entries(project))}
                <Typography
                    variant="subtitle1"
                    sx={{ fontWeight: 'bold', ml: 2 }}
                    value={Object.entries(project)[0][0]}>
                    {Object.entries(project)[0][0]}
                </Typography>
                {Object.entries(project)[0][1].map((ticket, ticketIndex) => (<MenuItem key={ticketIndex} sx={{ ml: 3 }} value={ticket}>{ticket}</MenuItem>))}
            </Box> 
        ))}
    </Box>
```

but if you have access to make changes in the backend I will recommend to save the data like this:

```
[
{
 "projectName": "Project 1"
    "tickets": [
        "Ticket 1",
        "Ticket 2",
        "Ticket 3",
    ]
},
{
  "projectName": "Project 2"
    "tickets": [
        "Ticket 4"
        "Ticket 5"
        "Ticket 6"
    ]
}
```

]

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ZWGOGg6.png
I'm getting this error when I try to use it. Not sure if I did something wrong. I just wrapped it in curly braces.

Comment: I edit my answer and now I think it should work note: you need to import Box component from material ui or you can just use a regular div element instead of the Box

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of objects. In this objects you have only one properties. That properties is another array of string.

I do not know what is component Typography exatly doing and will be my solution good for your code and optimization but.
you can try somthing like this:

Before rendering component (not JSX)

```
let backEndValue = [
  {
    "Project 1": [
      "Ticket 1",
      "Ticket 2",
      "Ticket 3",
    ]
  },
  {
    "Project 2": [
      "Ticket 4",
      "Ticket 5",
      "Ticket 6",
    ]
  }
]
const [title,setTitle] = useState('');
const [subTitle,setSubTitle] = useState('');

setProjects = [];

Object.keys(backEndValue).map((prop) => {
  return setProjects.push(backEndValue[prop]);
})
setProjects.map((prop)=>{
  const temp = Object.keys(prop);
  const tempT = prop[temp];

  setTitle(temp);
  setSubTitle(tempT);
})
```

In rendering (JSX)

```
{
title.map((prop,index)=>{
return <Typography key={index} variant="subtitle1" sx={{fontWeight: 'bold', ml: 2}} value={prop}>{prop}</Typography>
})
}
{
subTitle.map((prop,index)=>{
return <MenuItem key={index} sx={{ml: 3}} value={prop}>{prop}</MenuItem>
})
}
```